# QGIS print composer export sequence of png images for zoom

Tags: qgis, print-composer, video

I would like to create a 2 second video zooming out of a map I made in QGIS.

It starts at 1:300 and ends at 1:4500.

At 24 frames a second I need to add 87.5 to the scale and export a png, then add another 87.5 to the scale and export a png and then repeat this 48 times.

How could I automate this?

I can add an image sequence to any non-linear video editor to convert it into other video formats afterwards.

Answer (score 7):

Use the Atlas generation tool in the print composer. You will need a Atlas Coverage layer with 48 identical polygons for your view area on top each other. You can draw one polygon and copy paste it 47 times (ctrl c / ctrl v). Set the coverage layer and define the incremental filenames.

[image]

With the Field Calculator create an attribute called scale with a value for first record of 300 add 88 for every record to the scale column using this expression:

```
$rownum + 299 + (($rownum - 1) * 88)
```

I used integer with no decimals in this example

[image]

Then data bind the scale column to the Item property Scale of the map. The button then turns yellow.

[image]

In the Item properties of the map the property 'Controlled by atlas' will set the margin of the map.

Use the Export Atlas as images.. button

[image]

Comment: great answer - just tried this (in 2.18.3) and it works. It also works with POINT layers for coverage too. I'd add that you need to make sure you enable "controlled by atlas" / "fixed scale" mode (at least when using points)